# bazel version me da error

Tags: vscode, bazel

En mi visual studio code abrí una nueva terminal y corrí el comando

```
bazel version
```

Lo cual me arroja el siguiente error:

> bazel : File C:\Program Files\nodejs\bazel.ps1 cannot be loaded
> because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more
> information,      see about_Execution_Policies at
> https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170. At line:1 char:1
>
> - bazel version
> - ```
>     + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
>   ```

Cabe destacar que si hago lo mismo en [intellij-idea](/questions/tagged/intellij-idea) todo funciona de maravilla

Answer (score 1):

Como dice la liga es un problema de permisos, todo parece indicar que vscode usa powershell para su terminal.

Lo resolví corriendo el siguiente comando para darle permisos:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
bazel version
```

> Build label: 2.1.0

> Build target: bazel-out/x64_windows-opt/bin/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/bazel/BazelServer_deploy.jar

> Build time: Fri Feb 7 13:02:33 2020 (1581080553)

> Build timestamp: 1581080553 Build timestamp as int: 1581080553